# How to Find the character height in the Eclipse SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have an Eclipse application there I need to find out the exact height of the area occupied by the text.

The method `GC.textExtent` method does not do the right job. It gives the same value for letters that have different sizes. The Arial font is not a monospace type font, so lowercase letters should have different sizes to upper case ones, for example.

The problem is that the rectangle returned by `GC.textExtent` does not fully enclose letters like "j" and "g" which have a "tail" going below the bottom line which goes beyond the extent. I want to fix that and make sure that the bounding box I draw around the text fully contains that text.

I tried to reduce the problem as much as possible to recreate the problem and here is the code. the static block in one of the Eclipse application views is executed to calculate initial parameters. But here I just find two integers and throw exceptions if they are not different. They should be.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;

class SomeClass {

  ...

  static {
        Image imgTemp = new Image(Display.getDefault(), 123, 123);
        GC gcTemp = new GC(imgTemp);
        Font fontTemp = new Font(Display.getDefault(), "Arial", 13, SWT.NORMAL);

        int shortStringSize = gcTemp.textExtent("a").y;
        int tallStringSize = gcTemp.textExtent("j").y;

        imgTemp.dispose();
        fontTemp.dispose();
        gcTemp.dispose();
        
        if (shortStringSize == tallStringSize) {
            throw new RuntimeException("I expected letter 'a' have smaller"
                    + " text extent than letter 'j', because it is visually"
                    + " shorter.\n"
                    + "'j' size = " 
                    + tallStringSize 
                    + "\n"
                    + "'a' size = "
                    + shortStringSize);
        }
  }

...

}
```

Output has errors.

```
<big stacktrace>

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: I expected letter 'a' have smaller text extent than letter 'j', because it is visually shorter.
'j' size = 21
'a' size = 21
    at <my file>

<big stacktrace>
```

Would there be a way to find a size of a string that depends on character height?

Comment: Monospace fonts about height, they're about width. This reads like a bug report for SWT itself, though, not something you'd correct in your own code.

Comment: `GC.getFontMetrics` gives the ascent and descent values for the font. The textExtent `y` value seems to be the sum of the ascent + descent.

Comment: `GC#textExtent(String)` returns a bounding box that includes the descender height.  For example, in a 12pt font I get a `y` value of 15, which is the sum of the ascender height and descender height.  I'm not sure what you're seeing that tells you otherwise.

Comment: Not really helpful, but some 15y ago I had the problem to determine the height and length in pixels for a given text and font. I turned out that there was a bug. Font metrics are complicated, and such bugs tend to be sticky, reappearing like zombie.